# Compare two dimensional arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two two-dimensional arrays,

```
a = [[17360, "Z51.89"],
 [17361, "S93.601A"],
 [17362, "H66.91"],
 [17363, "H25.12"],
 [17364, "Z01.01"],
 [17365, "Z00.121"],
 [17366, "Z00.129"],
 [17367, "K57.90"],
 [17368, "I63.9"]]
```

and

```
b = [[17360, "I87.2"],
 [17361, "s93.601"],
 [17362, "h66.91"],
 [17363, "h25.12"],
 [17364, "Z51.89"],
 [17365, "z00.121"],
 [17366, "z00.129"],
 [17367, "k55.9"],
 [17368, "I63.9"]]
```

I would like to count similar rows in both the arrays irrespective of the character case, i.e., `"h25.12"` would be equal to `"H25.12"`.

I tried,

```
count = a.count - (a - b).count
```

But `(a - b)` returns

```
[[17360, "Z51.89"],
 [17361, "S93.601A"],
 [17362, "H66.91"],
 [17363, "H25.12"],
 [17364, "Z01.01"],
 [17365, "Z00.121"],
 [17366, "Z00.129"],
 [17367, "K57.90"]]
```

I need the count as `5` since there are five similar rows when we do not consider the character case.

Comment: Those aren't two dimensional arrays, Ruby has no such thing (unless you want to count `Matrix`), those are just arrays-of-arrays.

Comment: Ok!! That means Ruby has no 'Two Dimensional Array' by convention?

Comment: That means that there are no two dimensional arrays period.

Comment: Do you want to compare the ith element of `a` with the ith element of `b` or with any element of 'b`? (Your example suggests the former.) If the latter, can there be duplicate elements, and if so, how are duplicates to be counted?

Comment: good question! Mine is the former one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `a - b` you should do this:

```
a.map{|k,v| [k,v.downcase]} - b.map{|k,v| [k,v.downcase]} # case-insensitive
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert Arrays to Hash, and use [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) with a block.

```
b_hash = b.to_h
a.to_h.count {|k, v| b_hash[k] && b_hash[k].downcase == v.downcase }
# => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It will convert second element of inner array to upcase for both array then you can perform subtraction, then It will return exact result that you want

```
a.map{|first,second| [first,second.upcase]} - b.map{|first,second| [first,second.upcase]}
```

Comment: Consider explaning your anwser!

Answer (score 1):

You can zip them and then use the block form of count:

```
a.zip(b).count{|e| e[0][1].downcase == e[1][1].downcase}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.count - (a.map{|e| [e[0],e[1].downcase] } - b.map{|e| [e[0],e[1].downcase] }).count
```

The above maps `a` and `b` to new arrays where the second sub-array element is downcase.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count similar, so &(AND) operation is more suitable.

```
(a.map { |k, v| [k, v.upcase] } & b.map { |k, v| [k, v.upcase] }).count
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) and '[&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26)':

```
procedure = Proc.new { |i, j| [i, j.upcase] }
(a.map(&procedure) & b.map(&procedure)).count
#=> 5
```

For better understanding, let's simplify it:

```
new_a = a.map {|i, j| [i, j.upcase]}
new_b = b.map {|i, j| [i, j.upcase]}

# Set intersection using '&'
(new_a & new_b).count
#=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the ith element of `a` is to be compared with the ith element of `b`. (Edit: a subsequent comment by the OP confirmed this interpretation.)

I would be inclined to use indices to avoid the construction of relatively large temporary arrays. Here are two ways that might be done.

**#1 Use indices**

```
[a.size,b.size].min.size.times.count do |i|
  af,al=a[i]
  bf,bl=b[i]; 
  af==bf && al.downcase==bl.downcase
end
  #=> 5
```

**#2 Use `Refinements`**

My purpose in giving this solution is to illustrate the use of [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). I would not argue for its use for the problem at hand, but this problem provides a good vehicle for showing how the technique can be applied.

I could not figure out how best to do this, so I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290275/using-refinements-hierarchically) on SO. I've applied @ZackAnderson's answer below.

```
module M
  refine String do
    alias :dbl_eql :==
    def ==(other)
      downcase.dbl_eql(other.downcase)
    end
  end

  refine Array do
    def ==(other)
      zip(other).all? {|x, y| x == y}
    end
  end
end

'a' == 'A'         #=> false (as expected)
[1,'a'] == [1,'A'] #=> false (as expected)

using M
'a' == 'A'         #=> true
[1,'a'] == [1,'A'] #=> true
```

I could use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), but for variety I'll use [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) and [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) in conjunction with [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
ea, eb = a.to_enum, b.to_enum
cnt = 0
loop do
   cnt += 1 if ea.next == eb.next
end
cnt #=> 5
```