# Using Refinements Hierarchically

Tags: ruby, refinements

[Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) was an experimental addition to v2.0, then modified and made permanent in v2.1. It provides a way to avoid "monkey-patching" by providing "a way to extend a class locally".

I attempted to apply `Refinements` to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248748/compare-two-dimensional-arrays/29250291#29250291) which I will simplify thus:

```
a = [[1, "a"],
     [2, "b"],
     [3, "c"],
     [4, "d"]]

b = [[1, "AA"],
     [2, "B"],
     [3, "C"],
     [5, "D"]]
```

The element at offset `i` in `a` matches the element at offset `i` in `b` if:

```
a[i].first == b[i].first
```

and

```
a[i].last.downcase == b[i].last.downcase
```

In other words, the matching of the strings is independent of case.

The problem is to determine the number of elements of `a` that match the corresponding element of `b`. We see that the answer is two, the elements at offsets `1` and `2`.

One way to do this is to monkey-patch [String#==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D):

```
class String
  alias :dbl_eql :==
  def ==(other)
    downcase.dbl_eql(other.downcase)
  end
end

a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae.zip(be).all? { |aee,bee| aee==bee } }
  #=> 2
```

or instead use `Refinements`:

```
module M
  refine String do
    alias :dbl_eql :==
    def ==(other)
      downcase.dbl_eql(other.downcase)
    end
  end
end

'a' == 'A'
  #=> false (as expected)
a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae.zip(be).all? { |aee,bee| aee==bee } }
  #=> 0 (as expected)

using M
'a' == 'A'
  #=> true
a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae.zip(be).all? { |aee,bee| aee==bee } }
  #=> 2
```

However, I would like to use `Refinements` like this:

```
using M
a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae == be }
  #=> 0
```

but, as you see, that gives the wrong answer. That's because I'm invoking [Array#==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D) and the refinement does not apply within `Array`.

I could do this:

```
module N
  refine Array do
    def ==(other)
      zip(other).all? do |ae,be|
        case ae
        when String
          ae.downcase==be.downcase
        else
          ae==be
        end
      end  
    end
  end
end

using N
a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae == be }
  #=> 2
```

but that's not what I want. I want to do something like this:

```
module N
  refine Array do
    using M
  end   
end

using N
a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae == be }
  #=> 0
```

but clearly that does not work.

My question: is there a way to refine `String` for use in `Array`, then refine `Array` for use in my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was *really* interesting to play around with! Thanks for asking this question! I found a way that works!

```
module M
  refine String do
    alias :dbl_eql :==
      def ==(other)
        downcase.dbl_eql(other.downcase)
      end
  end

  refine Array do
    def ==(other)
      zip(other).all? {|x, y| x == y}
    end
  end
end

a = [[1, "a"],
     [2, "b"],
     [3, "c"],
     [4, "d"]]

b = [[1, "AA"],
     [2, "B"],
     [3, "C"],
     [5, "D"]]

using M

a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae == be } # 2
```

Without redefining `==` in `Array`, the refinement won't apply. Interestingly, it also doesn't work if you do it in two separate modules; this doesn't work, for instance:

```
module M
  refine String do
    alias :dbl_eql :==
      def ==(other)
        downcase.dbl_eql(other.downcase)
      end
  end
end

using M

module N
  refine Array do
    def ==(other)
      zip(other).all? {|x, y| x == y}
    end
  end
end

a = [[1, "a"],
     [2, "b"],
     [3, "c"],
     [4, "d"]]

b = [[1, "AA"],
     [2, "B"],
     [3, "C"],
     [5, "D"]]

using N

a.zip(b).count { |ae,be| ae == be } # 0
```

I'm not familiar enough with the implementation details of `refine` to be totally confident about why this behavior occurs. My guess is that the inside of a refine block is treated sort of as entering a different top-level scope, similarly to how refines defined outside of the current file only apply if the file they are defined in is parsed with `require` in the current file. This would also explain why nested refines don't work; the interior refine goes out of scope the moment it exits. This would *also* explain why monkey-patching `Array` as follows works:

```
class Array
  using M

  def ==(other)
    zip(other).all? {|x, y| x == y}
  end
end
```

This doesn't fall prey to the scoping issues that `refine` creates, so the `refine` on `String` stays in scope.

Comment: That's great! One detail: you might consider replacing `!self.zip(other).map {|x, y| x == y}.include? false` with `zip(other).all? {|x, y| x == y}`. (Recall that `self` is the default receiver.)

Comment: Ah, yeah, thanks—I've acquired a bad habit of using `self` everywhere it could apply. This will help me remember to consider whether or not it makes sense to use. It does look much nicer/more readable here without `self` and using `all?`.

Comment: Many Rubyists use `self` when it's not needed because they believe its omission may be confusing to the reader. I'm not in that camp, but I cannot say they are wrong.

Comment: It seems like it really depends on the situation to me. There are times when I would deliberately use `self` where it could be omitted, but in this case it seems like the line of code is so simple that it's easier to read if `self` is left out. If it was a more complex/unusual line of code it might be easier to make immediate sense of if `self` was used.